# IONIC: unable to get records from two `ng-repeat`

Tags: android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new with ionic framework.Currently i am working on `ionicsidemenu` app. I want to show records according to date, having date as heading  and respective  date having multiple records.

For this i have two `web services` one is  for heading date another is for date-wise records. In my HTML file i have two `ng-repeat` one is for display heading  date. Now i am not able to understand how to get records of particular date as date has to be sent to web service  for getting records.

I have tried this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="d in dates track by $index">
 <h2>d.edate</h2>
 <div ng-init="datewiserecords(d.edate);" >
 <div ng-repeat="n in res1  track by $index" class="text-white"  >
 </div></div></div>
```

but its not working.Please help me.

Comment: try to print `{{dates}}` and `{{res1}}` so you will come to know if it has value or not

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but the way I understand the question makes me to give you a solution as below:

My Solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="get_date in dates">
            <h2>{{get_date.date}}</h2>
            <h4>{{get_date.data}}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [{date:"1",data:"One"},{date:"2",data:"Two"},{date:"3",data:"Three"}];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope This is helpful

Comment: Thank you so much @ram for the answer but i have multiple records of same date and dates and its records comes from another web service.